# Spring-JPA Repository как сделать свой query типа List<T> FindByID(int id)

Tags: java, repository, spring-jpa

Это мое первое приложение на Spring. Использовал SpringBOOT, Maven, SpringMVC, Thymeleaf, SpringJPA, MySQL.

Подскажите пожалуйста, код нормально работает с методами предопределенными в интерфейсе Repository(CrudRepository или PagingAndSortingRepository), но когда пытаюсь создать свое query, то проект не компилируется с ошибкой:

> Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property status found for type Item! Did you mean 'state'

ItemRepository.java

```
import com.heiko.to_do_list.model.Item;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, Integer> {
    List<Item> findByStatus(boolean stateVal);
}
```

ItemController.java

```
import com.heiko.to_do_list.model.Item;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

@Controller
public class ItemController {
@Autowired
private ItemRepository dao;
private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ListItems(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("items", dao.findAll());
    return "items/list";
    }
}
```

добавил в папку recources, spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <repositories base-package="com.heiko.to_do_list.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

не помогает.

Ссылка на GIT: [Git](https://github.com/YuriHeiko/Simple_TODO_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No property status found for type Item! Did you mean 'state'

Примерный перевод:

> Необходимое свойство в типе Item не найдено! Возможно вы имели ввиду 'state'.

Другими словами у вам в классе `Item` нет поля `status`, но есть `state`, его и нужно использовать.
Как по вашему Spring догадается какое поле нужно использовать? Он определяет это по имени.

Замените `findByStatus(...)` на `findByState(...)`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все так и есть, глаза замылились простейшую ошибку не увидел :(